# AWS: is it possible to use Step Functions to call LEX

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-lex

I'm trying to create a **Step Function** to call **LEX** to get **intents** from text. Is it possible to call LEX using step functions or I need to use lambdas?

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html) doesn't list LEX as a supported service, but I want to be 100% sure before committing to use lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to invoke a Lex bot directly from Step Functions.

As you mentioned, if you have to do it, invoke a Lambda function from your Step Function. The Lambda function can then further use the Lex runtime API operations to invoke the Lex bot: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations_Amazon_Lex_Runtime_Service.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I am using Lambdas by the moment. It works okay but it will be better not having and adapter between the two services.